# Is it possible to open the plot viewer within Visual code studio?

Tags: r, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina, xquartz

With Visual Code Studio installed on Mac OS Catalina, I'm using the [vscode-R](https://github.com/Ikuyadeu/vscode-R) extension, however when creating a plot, a new plot window opens up in xquartz [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJTmV.png). This is not ideal.

Is possible to open the plot viewer within VS code studio?

Mac OS: v10.15.4
VS Code studio: v1.45.1
vscode-R: v0.6.1

Answer (score 1):

You need the latest vscode-R extension and enable the R session watcher to show plot in VSCode. Please take a look at https://github.com/Ikuyadeu/vscode-R/wiki/R-Session-watcher.